# How to copy a certain amount of sorted files? (e.g. 11 GB)

Tags: files, sort, cp

I'd like to copy a total of 11 GB of files (all of the type `.mp3` for the sake of this question) from folder `~/ABC/` to `~/DEF/`. And I like to do that for the files sorted descending by date last edited/modified in ABC (i.e. the file modified most recently should get copied first).

The file names contain spaces and or characters like `&`, `.` and `/` and alike.

I have looked around a bit and so far, and using code from (somewhat) related questions does not look sensible imho (not that I would be a good judge anyway).

How can I go about that? :)

Comment: similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97177/117549

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this.
LIMIT is the amount to copy in kilobytes.

```
#! /bin/bash 

LIMIT='11534336'
size='0'

if [[ -e $1 && -d $2 ]];then
  echo "copying contents from $1 to $2"
else
  echo "Usage: $0 SOURCE DEST"
  exit
fi  

for i in $(ls -t $1); do
  var="$(echo $(du -s $(realpath $1/$i)))"
  IFS=" " read var1 var2 <<< "$var"
  let "size += $var1"
  if [[ $size -lt $LIMIT ]];then
    echo "copying " $var2 "to $2"
    cp -r $var2 $2
  else
    exit
  fi  
done
```